# efficient mean of solving constrained OLS problems?

Tags: optimization, least-squares, constrained-optimization

I was wondering whether there was a efficient procedure for solving 
constrained quadratic approximations of the form:

$$\underset{k\in \mathbb{R}}{\min}\;||x_i-kx_0||_2$$

for fixed values of $x_0,x_i\in \mathbb{R}^d$. This needs to be solved recursively for a large number of values of $x_i$ for fixed $x_0$ (so if there is a way to parametrize the solution in terms of $x_i$, that will be helpful).

Currently, I'm using an iterative algorithm (in R):

```
set.seed(123)
d<-100
n<-50
xi<-matrix(rnorm(n*d),n,d)
x0<-rnorm(d)
ff<-function(k,xi,x0,ll){
    crossprod(xi[ll,]-k*x0)
}
optimize(ff,lower=-1000,upper=1000,xi=xi,x0=x0,ll=13)$min
```

Comment: Where are your constraints?

Comment: What is the constraint you are talking about? As it is written now, the optimal k follows by simply differentiating the expression, leading to $x_0^Tx_0/(x_0^Tx_i)$

Comment: @JohanLöfberg: thanks, this is the solution i was looking for [well, it's the inverse of the expression you wrote]-- can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Ah, so both $x_0$ and the $x_i$ are fixed. You should revise your question accordingly, and remove the x-es from below the min sign. As it stands now, the formula is misleading.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier: ok i will (i tought that the "|" made it clear that x0 and x1 were given

Comment: Much better now. But I still see no constraints. The constraints should be under the min, such as $\min_{k\in~[a,b]}$.

Comment: You should also clarify the question in the discussion of Jughurta's answer. Do you want to have a new optimal $k$ for each $x_i$, or a single $k$ for all $x_i$ simultaneously. As it stands now, it means the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By squaring the expression and differentiating w.r.t $k$, it follows that the unconstrained solution is $x_0^Tx_i/(x_0^Tx_0)$. If $k$ is bounded, the optimal solution is obtained by clipping the solution at the bound.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by Restricted Least Squares. If your constraints on $k$ are linear you should even have a closed form solution for $\hat{k}$.

Comment: $k$ is an unconstrained scalar (or a $d$ vector with $k-1$ linear restrictions). I suspect there is a closed form.

Comment: Yes there is, for example here at pag 6. Just substitute $\beta$ with $k$:

http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww2.econ.iastate.edu%2Fclasses%2Fecon671%2Fhallam%2Fdocuments%2FRestricted_Testing_000.pdf&ei=E0J9UKTkK6O70QXasYHYDA&usg=AFQjCNEFTPc_q9p5hl2_ojkKt7REMpPggQ&sig2=rEvfV7CUQk9OKXdjd6ahJw

Comment: no, it is not the same. In your example $\beta$ has the same # of component as $x$. In my example this is not the case (basically, you are ignoring the $k-1$ linear restriction)....

Comment: Johan gives the right uncostrained solution for one $x_i$.  The solution of the overall uncontrained problem is $\frac{x_0^T \bar{x}}{x^T_0 x_0}$, where $\bar{x}$ is the mean of all the $x_i$. Now the constraint must be added in.

Comment: So if it is intended to be the sum of the squared norms in the objective, then the question has to be updated. As it is asked now, it asks for an efficient way to compute optimal k, for varying $x_i$, given that $x_0$ is fixed (Which is exploited by using the fact that $x_0^Tx_0$ is unchanged when solving for different $x_i$, i.e, one inner product can be eliminated)

Comment: That's how I understand it, also looking at the code. $x_i$ in the code is a matrix and $k$ is a scalar, so he doesn't want to do a regression for each $x_i$. So for me there should be a $\sum_{i=1}^N$ in front of the objective.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the [ll,] in the code, so we just wants a $k$ for each $x_i$.